# bash script works with in debug only

Tags: bash

I'm trying to remove characters from a file name.

#### files

```
#ls
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary (AutoFlac).flac
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary (AutoFlac).log
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.cue
```

What I want for output:

```
#ls
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.cue
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.flac
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.log
```

#### script

```
#!/bin/bash
SUFFIX="(AutoFLAC)"
#search directory for file with a suffix of (AutoFLAC)
for entry in *$SUFFIX*
do
   #remove a leading space and (AutoFLAC) from the file name
   FILENAME=`echo $entry | sed 's/ (AutoFLAC)//'`
   echo "$entry"
   echo "$FILENAME"
   #change the old file name for the new file name
   mv  "$entry" "$FILENAME"
 done
```

If I add `-x`, it works.

```
Mac-Attack:edit-file-names $ ./edit-file-names1.sh 
+ SUFFIX='(AutoFLAC)'
+ for entry in '*$SUFFIX*'
++ echo Peter, Paul '&' Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary '(AutoFLAC).flac'
++ sed 's/ (AutoFLAC)//'
+ FILENAME='Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.flac'
+ echo 'Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary (AutoFLAC).flac'
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary (AutoFLAC).flac
+ echo 'Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.flac'
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.flac
+ mv 'Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary (AutoFLAC).flac' 
'Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.flac'
+ for entry in '*$SUFFIX*'
++ echo Peter, Paul '&' Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary '(AutoFLAC).log'
++ sed 's/ (AutoFLAC)//'
+ FILENAME='Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.log'
+ echo 'Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary (AutoFLAC).log'
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary (AutoFLAC).log
+ echo 'Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.log'
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.log
+ mv 'Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary (AutoFLAC).log' 'Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.log'
Mac-Attack:edit-file-names $ ls
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.cue
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.flac
Peter, Paul & Mary - The Very Best of Peter, Paul and Mary.log
```

Without the `-x`:

```
Mac-Attack:edit-file-names $ ./edit-file-names2.sh 
*(AutoFLAC)*
*(AutoFLAC)*
mv: rename *(AutoFLAC)* to *(AutoFLAC)*: No such file or directory
```

Insights, thoughts?

Comment: @Mat, you just beat me to it. I was literally working on it right now :)

Comment: What's `-x`? Apologies for bugging you, but I've never heard of it.

Comment: @njsg: see `man set`, "The shell shall write to standard error a trace for each command after it expands the command and before it executes  it...."

Answer (score 4):

There's evidently something odd going on around case-insensitive wildcard matching. According to the `ls` output, the file names contain `(AutoFlac)`, whereas your script looks for `(AutoFLAC)`. Unix tools traditionally consider two file names to be the same only if they're byte-for-byte identical; there's nothing built-in for case-insensitive matching. Bash seems to behave inconsistently on a case-insensitive filesystem, this may be a bug.

Your script would be more robust if you used double quotes around variable substitutions. If you don't, bash (like other shells) performs globbing on the result of the variable substitution. This may be the source of your trouble. **Always put double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions: `"$foo"`, `"$(foo)"`** unless you know you want to perform word splitting and globbing on the result. Also your script with the missing double quotes wouldn't work on some file names, e.g. with whitespace sequences that aren't a single space.

I also recommend doing the text substitution inside the shell, there's less risk of mangling file names that way.

```
SUFFIX="(AutoFlac)"
for entry in *"$SUFFIX"*; do
  target=${entry/ $SUFFIX/}
  mv -- "$entry" "$target"
done
```

There's no way to force case-insensitive wildcard matching, but you can make your script ignore case by doing your own matching.

```
SUFFIX="(autoflac)"
for entry in *; do
  if [[ ${entry,,} = *$SUFFIX* ]]; then
    # Remove everything from the last space to the last .
    mv -- "$entry" "${entry% *}.${entry##*.}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: @forcefsck My reply was to the final version of your comment. I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: Nevermind. I'll delete this later.

Answer (score 0):

If the shell finds no matching files for a glob pattern, it will run the loop once with the glob pattern intact. *(AutoFLAC)* is your entry because of this behavior.

Comment: If you use `shopt -s nullglob`, non-matching patterns (glob) will be replaced by nothing (null).

Comment: Just a note: that is bash only, so on Debian/Ubuntu or *BSD you will need to make sure the script is interpreted by bash.

Comment: Well, the question is tagged [bash]

Comment: Yeah your advice is good. Just making sure that the OP does not use `#! /bin/sh` and wonder why it does not work.